# How does cartilage become bone?

Tags: bone-biology, cartilage

It's a famous fact that bones begin as cartilage and later become bone, but I never was clear *how exactly*
 this changeover occurs. Could someone please explain this to me?

Comment: What research have you done? What exactly you are unable to understand? Show your efforts.

Comment: Homework questions are off-topic on Biology unless you have shown your attempt at an answer. For more information see our [homework policy](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework).

Comment: FYI: [Why is cartilage replaced by bones in an vertebrae adult?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/80900/630)

Answer (score 3):

The process is called [endochondral ossification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endochondral_ossification).

It is important to point out that not all bone is derived from cartilage. For example, when a bone is fractured and is healing, the new bone does not always come from cartilage, rather [intramembranous ossification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intramembranous_ossification) occurs. There are therefore multiple mechanisms at a microscopic level by which bone may form. Additionally, bone formation in the long bones is different to that in, for example, the flat bones of the skull.